# C# .NET MySQL (MariaDB) Not Saving Data Yet Returning Sucess

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, mariadb

Intermittently in production (not repeatable in local, dev, or UAT environments) data will not save to the database even though the MysqlClient is returning success and number of rows updated.

The application server for production is `IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008`

This application server communicates with 2 separate database servers.

One on Ubuntu `Linux servername 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` 
`+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                            |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.39-83.1                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                               |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                  |
| version                 | 10.1.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 |
| version_comment         | Ubuntu 18.04                     |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                           |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu                 |
| version_malloc_library  | system jemalloc                  |
| version_ssl_library     | YaSSL 2.4.4                      |
| wsrep_patch_version     | wsrep_25.23                      |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+`

And another on Fedora `Linux servername 4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 9 14:51:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`+-------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name           | Value           |
+-------------------------+-----------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.32-79.0     |
| protocol_version        | 10              |
| slave_type_conversions  |                 |
| version                 | 10.0.28-MariaDB |
| version_comment         | MariaDB Server  |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64          |
| version_compile_os      | Linux           |
| version_malloc_library  | system          |
+-------------------------+-----------------+`

Heh, please don't ask about the wildly different database servers. Anyways, they both exhibit the same problems.

The application is in `.NET 4.5` and uses `MysqlConnector Mysql.Data dll 6.9.4` to communicate with both databases.

Sporadically (under heavy load (in terms of what the system usually gets); around 25 concurrent users) the system will begin to not save changes to the database even though the application is getting success back from code such as `int x = Sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` where x is the number of rows updated.

This will happen with very basic Mysql updates such as

`MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(TheConnectionString()); conn.Open();
        try
        {
            string Query = "DELETE FROM A_TABLE WHERE USERID = '" + UserID + "'";
            MySqlCommand Sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            Sqlcmd.CommandText = Query;
            Sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally { if (conn != null) { conn.Close(); conn.Dispose(); } }`

Please ignore the obviously poor written sql statement that is prone to sql injection.

Other ways of database interaction (using transactions) also show the same behavior.

```
    //Create and Instantiate the Connection
        sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(strConnect);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        //With Transaction
        if (bWithTrans == true)
        {
            sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
            //sqlTransaction.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.
            bRollBack = false; // Reset indicator
        }

        sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(qryString, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandText = qryString;

        //With Transaction
        if (bWithTrans == true)
        {
            sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
        }
...
...
       if (IsInTransaction())
        {
            if (bRollBack == true)
            {
                sqlTransaction.Rollback();
            }
            else
            {
                sqlTransaction.Commit();
            }
            sqlTransaction.Connection.Close();
            sqlTransaction.Connection.Dispose();
            sqlTransaction = null;
        }
```

I've omitted a lot of code from the above (such as the closing part.) Please ignore the lack of `using {}` statement (I'm 99% sure every connection is closed.)

During the times where data is not saved, the following appears in `select * from information_schema.innodb_trx`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    trx_id: 302303150
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2018-09-27 08:56:45
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 0
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 117343
                 trx_query: NULL
       trx_operation_state: NULL
         trx_tables_in_use: 0
         trx_tables_locked: 0
          trx_lock_structs: 0
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 360
           trx_rows_locked: 0
         trx_rows_modified: 0
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 0
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 10000
          trx_is_read_only: 0
trx_autocommit_non_locking: 0
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    trx_id: 302303150
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2018-09-27 08:56:45
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 0
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 117343
                 trx_query: NULL
       trx_operation_state: NULL
         trx_tables_in_use: 0
         trx_tables_locked: 0
          trx_lock_structs: 0
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 360
           trx_rows_locked: 0
         trx_rows_modified: 0
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 0
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 10000
          trx_is_read_only: 0
trx_autocommit_non_locking: 0
```

It is very weird to see `trx_query: NULL`... I have a script to print this table every 0.1 seconds, and it will ONLY ever show `trx_query: NULL` when data is not saving to the database (yet reporting that it is.)

During this time, a `show engine innodb status` produces this in the TRANSACTIONS section...

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 147254697
Purge done for trx's n:o < 147254674 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 30
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 222904, OS thread handle 0x7f7a6e08b700, query id 617593737 localhost root init
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 147254688, not started
MySQL thread id 222902, OS thread handle 0x7f7a23a5f700, query id 617593732 10.22.18.39 DB_NAME
---TRANSACTION 147254696, not started
MySQL thread id 222901, OS thread handle 0x7f7a239c9700, query id 617593736 10.22.18.39 DB_NAME
---TRANSACTION 147254644, not started
MySQL thread id 222900, OS thread handle 0x7f7a6e027700, query id 617593526 10.22.18.39 DB_NAME
---TRANSACTION 147254684, not started
MySQL thread id 222897, OS thread handle 0x7f7a6b4e9700, query id 617593709 10.22.18.39 DB_NAME
---TRANSACTION 147240473, not started
MySQL thread id 126445, OS thread handle 0x7f7a23af5700, query id 617593614 10.22.18.41 DB_NAME
---TRANSACTION 84024323, not started
MySQL thread id 1, OS thread handle 0x7f7a6e185700, query id 0 Waiting for background binlog tasks
---TRANSACTION 147254695, ACTIVE 1 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 0
MySQL thread id 222898, OS thread handle 0x7f7a239fb700, query id 617593734 10.22.18.39 DB_NAME Sending data
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE I'M HIDING FOR PRIVACY
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 147254696, sees < 147254696
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
```

I'm not seeing anything in terms of a deadlock.

What I've tried...

- Since the DB's are different in terms of OS and versions, I have a
  hard time believing it is a Mysql (MariaDB) problem.
- I've tried changing the Mysql Connector dll from 6.9.4 to 6.9.10 and
  6.9.12
- I've set the application to recycle it's app-pool every 1 hour in
  IIS, the problem has been seen 1 minute after a recycle.
- I've commented out the `.beginTransaction()` stuff, so that the
  default AUTO-COMMIT is executed after every `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

**edit here is the query log logged to a file (i edited the sql to remove table/column names for privacy)

```
245133 Query    ROLLBACK
                245671 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on
                245671 Query    select * from information_schema.innodb_trx
                244093 Query    ROLLBACK
                245671 Quit
                245133 Init DB  DB_NAME
                245133 Query    SELECT `DESC` as Status FROM TABLE WHERE REC_NUM != 2 ORDER BY `REC_NUM`
                245133 Query    ROLLBACK
                244093 Init DB  DB_NAME
                244093 Query    SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN IN (SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE STATUSCODE = 3) ORDER BY COLUMN
                244093 Query    ROLLBACK
                245133 Init DB  DB_NAME
                245133 Query    SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE GROUP BY COLUMN ORDER BY COLUMN
                245133 Query    ROLLBACK
                244093 Init DB  DB_NAME
                244093 Query    SELECT COLUMN as Status FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN <> 1 AND COLUMN <> 2 AND COLUMN <> 4 AND COLUMN <> 10 AND COLUMN <> 11
AND COLUMN <> 12 AND COLUMN <> 13  AND COLUMN <> 15 ORDER BY REC_NUM
                244093 Query    ROLLBACK
                245133 Init DB  DB_NAME
                245133 Query    SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'DB_NAME'
                245133 Query    ROLLBACK
                245248 Query    ROLLBACK
                244093 Init DB  DB_NAME
                245133 Init DB  DB_NAME
```

Crazy to see so many ROLLBACKS... what could be causing this. In my comment below I show ROLLBACK in tcpdump in app_server > db_server so it's not the DB initiating these rollbacks.

Comment: My guess is an exception is thrown and the transaction is rolled back. You should add some logging to find out.

Comment: @DavidLibido thanks for your comment. The data is not saving even when not using a transaction.

Comment: I can't doubt the rollback, but can a rollback happen without an explicit `.rollback()`?... here is tcpdump of database server and it shows a rollback... `13:57:58.830419 IP 10.22.18.39.49804 > 10.22.18.246.3306: Flags [P.], seq 242305:242318, ack 3237214, win 508, length 13
        0x0000:  4500 0035 06d2 4000 8006 baa8 0a16 1227  E..5..@........'
        0x0010:  0a16 12f6 c28c 0cea c7e1 07c4 19e6 d958  ...............X
        0x0020:  5018 01fc adfb 0000 0900 0000 0352 4f4c  P............ROL
        0x0030:  4c42 4143 4b                             LBACK`

Comment: Yes, if a transaction is not committed (due to an exception maybe) it's eventually rolled back.

Comment: You've mentioned the SQL injection vulnerability, and the missing `using` block for the connection; but the command and the transaction are also disposable so should also be in `using` blocks. Once those are in place, you won't need to Close or Dispose the connection. From the code in the question as it stands, the connection is only closed if a transaction is used.

Comment: @Richardissimo thanks for your comment, and you're correct. I omitted a lot of code from my original question, all of those disposable objects are closed outside of the example shown. Thanks again

Comment: You are mistaken. For example: The injection-vulnerable `DELETE` doesn't dispose the command...

Comment: Oh I see, you are saying even my basic example, an explicit .close() needs to be called on sqlCmd object?

Comment: No, I'm saying it needs to be in a `using` block, because it's `IDisposable`: so it is `Dispose` which needs to be called, not `Close`... `Dispose` will call `Close`, not vice-versa. Put anything which is `IDisposable` in a `using` block. Avoid trying to call `Dispose` explicitly yourself, because it's much harder to do it properly that way... it's actually *easier* to use a `using` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I believe I found the problem.

A very common Stored Procedure that the application calls a lot had this statement in it...

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
```

I've learned from another post that the `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0` is unnecessary (and is most likely my culprit.)

Before I ran the SP, `show variables like 'autocommit'` returned `ON` after the SP ran, it said `OFF`

My theory is connections that called that SP had their session variable of autocommit set to `OFF` and then returned to the pool. Later on when a connection grabbed that session from the pool it then began to rollback every statement because `autocommit` was still off, and no explicit `COMMIT;` was ever sent.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Whose "connection pooling"?  Don't use it if it fails to reset all the `VARIABLES`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COLUMN
    FROM  TABLE
    WHERE  COLUMN IN (
        SELECT  COLUMN
            FROM  TABLE
            WHERE  STATUSCODE = 3
                     )
    ORDER BY  COLUMN
```

-->

```
SELECT column
    FROM table
    WHERE statuscode = 3
    ORDER BY column;
```

(If there are really two *different* tables, then *please* make that clear in your Question.  In that case, the improved query would need a `JOIN`.)

```
SELECT  COLUMN
    FROM  TABLE
    GROUP BY  COLUMN
    ORDER BY  COLUMN
```

-->

```
SELECT DISTINCT column
    FROM table
    ORDER BY column
```

and

```
SELECT  COLUMN as Status
    FROM  TABLE
    WHERE  COLUMN <> 1
      AND  COLUMN <> 2
      AND  COLUMN <> 4
      AND  COLUMN <> 10
      AND  COLUMN <> 11
      AND  COLUMN <> 12
      AND  COLUMN <> 13
      AND  COLUMN <> 15
    ORDER BY  REC_NUM
```

-->

```
SELECT column AS Status
    FROM table
    WHERE column NOT IN (1,2,4,10,11,12,13,15)
    ORDER BY rec_num
```

and

```
Why do this; the answer is obviously 'DB_NAME':

SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = 'DB_NAME'.
```